# Использование тега section в сайдбаре

Tags: html, html5

В сайдбаре идёт баннер, рубрики, форма подписки, видео с ютуба и опрос.

Подскажите для семантики в  html5 каждый пункт можно ли делать в `<section>` или что то из этого не подходит для `<section>` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<section>` - тег для блока, который не является чем-то другим типа `<header>`, `<nav>` и пр.
а вот надо ли каждую его внутренность оборачивать в `<section>` - не думаю. думаю, обернуть сайдбар в `<section>` будет достаточно